Replace if with two conditions by a try catch
I'am looking for a way to get rid of a getError() usage by replacing it by a try catch(), the part of code has an if with two conditions. I don't know how to do it in this case :
$topic = TopicHelper::get($this->id);

if ($topic->isAuthorised('read') && $topic->subscribe(1)) {
        $this->app->enqueueMessage(Text::_('COM_COMPONENT_POST_SUBSCRIBED_TOPIC'), 'success');

        // Activity integration
        $activity = KunenaFactory::getActivityIntegration();
        $activity->onAfterSubscribe($topic, 1);
} else {
        $this->app->enqueueMessage(Text::_('COM_COMPONENT_POST_NO_SUBSCRIBED_TOPIC') . ' ' . $topic->getError(), 'error');
}


Where you wish to catch() the exception is a decision that I cannot advise you on.  It feels to me that you mean to throw an exception in the else branch of your condition block.  Is this true?  Maybe I don't know your intention.  You don't merely wish to silence the error, right?  throw new Exception(Text::_('COM_COMPONENT_POST_NO_SUBSCRIBED_TOPIC') . ' ' . $topic->getError());

no it's not that, it's about the two methods in the if, they returns both an exception. how the try part will be to replace this if with this two conditions ?

Do you mean like this? https://3v4l.org/ouQEX

thanks, i have tried this way, it seems working

Wrap all method calls which potentially throw an exception in the try segment.
In the catch segment, present the exception's getMessage() string in your enqueueMessage() call.
Whenever an exception is thrown, execution in the try segment will immediately be abandoned and only one exception will be provided.
try {
    $topic = TopicHelper::get($this->id);
    $topic->isAuthorised('read'); // this guard call `throws an exception` instead of returning `false`
    $topic->subscribe(1); // this guard call `throws an exception` instead of returning `false`
    $this->app->enqueueMessage(Text::_('COM_COMPONENT_POST_SUBSCRIBED_TOPIC'), 'success');

    // Activity integration
    $activity = KunenaFactory::getActivityIntegration();
    $activity->onAfterSubscribe($topic, 1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->app->enqueueMessage(Text::_('COM_COMPONENT_POST_NO_SUBSCRIBED_TOPIC') . ' ' . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
}

